# What does "..it had fallen to Red as lion, and Pope as Christian, to supply it"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is a sentence from the short story "The Inhuman Condition" by Clive Barker.

> Some entertainment had been called for, and it had fallen to Red as lion, and Pope as Christian, to supply it.

Red is beating up Pope in this situation and the narrator is watching the scene. I would like to know what the comparisions to a lion and to a Christian mean.

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article on _Damnātiō ad bestiās_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damnatio_ad_bestias#Execution_of_Christians). Rather an unpleasant image to conjure up.

Comment: According to legend, during the time that Christianity was illegal in the Roman Empire, some of the spectacles seen in the Coliseum in Rome were Christians vs. lions.  Of course the Christians were not expected to survive.

Comment: I can accept an answer if either of the above users supply it !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to legend, during the time that Christianity was illegal in the Roman Empire, some of the spectacles seen in the Coliseum in Rome were Christians vs. lions. Of course the Christians were not expected to survive.

Janus Bahs Jacquet provided this link: [Damnatio ad Bestias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damnatio_ad_bestias#Execution_of_Christians)